# Is there a scripting language like LUA for javascript?

Tags: node.js

I'm building an MMO using Node.js, and I'd like some scripters from my team to create scripts (duh) for bosses and other scripted objects. My first thought was to have a folder on the server where people can upload javascript files and let node.js automatically read and parse every script in the directory, but I don't want them to be able to execute process.exit() for example, or other hazardous stuff.

Is there a solution that lets me control what functions the scripters are able to call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control what functions are they unable to call with [`vm`](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module.

For example,

```
vm.runInNewContext(userCode, {
    require: null,
    process: null,
    someFunc: function (x) { return x+1 },
    someData: { abc: 'def' }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Will javascript work as scripting language. I guess it should.
so, I think vm.runInNewContext is might be all you need.
Have a look at http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html